# Which computer-made song is this?

Tags: riddle, music, humor

Which computer-made song is this?

0113H

(And what computer made it?)

Comment: Hello upside down?

Comment: @Gamow more like horizontally flipped?

Comment: And I was thinking, 275, 275, what is the significance of 275...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The song is clearly supposed to be

> Hello

Which is a well known song by

> Adele

With some imagination it is pronounced the same as

> A Dell, a well known computer brand

Comment: I should have asked the question differently, because i was looking for the quote: "Hello from the other side"